# IRM Prevent Old Document Versions from Opening

Tags: 2010, 2013, document-library, information-management

Is it possible to force a user to download the most up-to-date version of document when they open an old downloaded version on their local drive?

I know IRM can require users to reauthenticate after X amount of time, and it can enforce permissions on documents that are shared via email, but I need to enforce a type of 'stale content' rule.

I'm currently working in Sharepoint foundation 2010, but it's possible that we'll be upgrading to 2013 within the next couple of months, so any information on possibility of this in either of these environments would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

There are two user permissions called "View Versions" and "Delete Versions" that need to be disabled. You can create a new permission level called something like - "Contribute - No Versioning" and just Copy the Contribute level, and delete these two user permissions. Then assign the permission level to those folks that you don't want to view versions.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288074(v=office.14).aspx